# Is there an API entrypoint to launch malware scan immediately without scheduling it (On Demand) in DeepSecurity 12?

Tags: python, api, deepsecurity

I am looking for an entrypoint in DeepSecurity 12 to launch malware scan "On Demand".
I only found a way to do it by creating a schedule task, but it is not conveniant for my needs.

Thanks a lot in advance guys,

Cheers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you do need to use the Scheduled Task API to launch a malware scan on demand. But do note that you can set the "run now" field of a scheduled task (new or existing) to "true" to trigger an immediate scan, which makes it more convenient.

Cheers,
Morgan

P.S. I work in R&D for Trend Micro.